# Icon not showing on context menu item with Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: contextmenu, firefox-addon-sdk

This is the structure of the files:

```
├── data
│   ├── icon.png
│   ├── upload.js
│   └── upload.js~
├── doc
│   └── main.md
├── icon.png
├── lib
│   ├── icon.png
│   ├── main.js
│   └── main.js~
├── package.json
├── package.json.backup
├── README.md
├── share2.xpi
└── test
    └── test-main.js
```

This is the code in `main.js`:

```
const contextMenu = require("context-menu");
const data = require("self").data;
exports.main = function(options,callbacks){
    var cm = require("context-menu").Item({
        label:"share it",
        contentScriptFile:data.url("upload.js"),
    image:data.url("icon.png")
    });
}
```

"share it" is displayed in the context menu, and the contentScriptFile is be excuted, but the image doesn't display. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't (or shouldn't) need `icon.png` in `lib/`.

Comment: For me using image:data.url("icon.png") for a 16x16 "icon.png" in the 'data' folder worked, using addon-sdk-1.14

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a sufficient version of the Add-on SDK; the 'image' property was only added in version 1.1. If you're using 1.0, you'll need to update. Otherwise, it should be working.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I am using the version 1.3 dowloaded from (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/dev-guide/addon-development/installation.html),but it couldn't work

Comment: Then is `icon.png` valid, the right size, etc.? Does anything interesting appear in the console when running the extension through `cfx run`?

Comment: Sorry to reply so late.I tried 16px,19px and 32px which didn't work."Could not read chrome manifest file '/tmp/tmpWqbFWK.mozrunner/extensions/jid1-X2MazapyCOmMuA@jetpack/chrome.manifest'."in the console

Comment: Sounds like an error somewhere... is package.json perhaps invalid? I suggest that you try the Add-on SDK mailing list.

Comment: I am sorry to reply so late,I tried many ways but could not solve the problem,I will solve it someday.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but from the comments on Chris' answer, it seems like the issue is not with the icon but with your upload script.
It could be that the run process never reaches the image property to add it.

Do you get the same error if you remove the image property altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it has worked for me:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
require("sdk/context-menu").Item({
  label: "Buscar lugar geográfico...",
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", self.postMessage);',
  onMessage: function () {
    doSearch();
  },
  image:self.data.url("logo.png")
});
```